# Cómo puedo usar el mismo adaptador para el ListView y el GridView de mi aplicación?

Tags: android, arrayadapter

Esta es mi clase Adapter:

```
    public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter{



    private Context context;
    private List<Iglesia> datosIglesias;



    public Adapter(Context context, List<Iglesia> datosIglesias) {
        this.context = context;
        this.datosIglesias = datosIglesias;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return datosIglesias.size();
    }


    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return datosIglesias.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return datosIglesias.get(position).getId();
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewgrup) {


        View v = View.inflate(context,R.layout.item_iglesias, null);


        ImageView ImageView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.img_iglesia);
        TextView Nombre = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txt_nombreiglesia);


        ImageView.setImageResource(datosIglesias.get(position).getFoto());
        Nombre.setText(datosIglesias.get(position).getNombre());
        return v;
    }
}
```

> ¿Cómo puedo usar el mismo adaptador para el ListView y el GridView de
>   mi aplicación?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como tu `Adapter` extiende de [BaseAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) esta sería la forma de configurarlo, debes tomar en cuenta que el `Adapter` recibe el contexto y ademas un `List` de objetos iglesia (`List<Iglesia>`) :

**ListView:**

```
listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
listView.setAdapter(new Adapter(this, datosIglesias));
```

**GridView:**

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
gridview.setAdapter(new Adapter(this, datosIglesias));
```